# Show and Hide Select Options

Tags: php, jquery, hide, html-select

I've created a very basic form that has 2 dropdown lists.

Each list contains the same entries:

```
<option value='1234:0'>Closed</option>
<option value='4567:2'>Open</option>
<option value='6857:1'>Dead</option>
<option value='9856:1'>Alive</option>
<option value='0000:0'>Other</option>
```

If an entry in dropdown 1 is selected, then that entry should be removed from dropdown 2

If a different entry is selected in dropdown 1, then that should be removed from dropdown 2 and the original entry returned to dropdown 2

if nothing is selected in dropdown 1, then all options should be shown in dropdown 2.

I've created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s59wj5yr/)**, showing how far I've got... it's not very far.

Can any one help with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').change(function () {

        var selected = $(this).val();   

        $("#test2 option").show();

        $("#test2 option[value='" + selected + "']").hide();

    }); 

});
```

If you want to use text you can try this

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').change(function () {

        var selected = $('option:selected', this).text();

        $("#test2 option").each(function(){

            if($(this).text() == selected) {

                $(this).hide();

            } else {

                $(this).show();
            }

        })

    }); 

});
```

Comment: is this possible by using text() also  ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of each the options are identical, you can use `value` attribute to select the match in second select.

```
$('form').on('change', 'select[name="test"]', function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#test2 option").show();
    $("#test2 option[value='" + selected + "']").hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s59wj5yr/6/)

Comment: Select **'closed'**, and then select another one - the **'closed'** value should be resetted. It's not. And the second dropdown does not hide any values at all.

Comment: " Now the issue with second dropdown not hiding values in first dropdown remains" this isn't needed